# Where can I ask questions where my post will not be deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028161/project-help-needed-some-basic-concepts-great-confusion-because-of-lack-of-prope

Where can I ask questions where my post will not be deleted because of "it difficult to say what is being asked". I mean general waste area covering questions like the one I asked in.... And please give links to help forums where there are experts like you before closing this question.

Comment: What if we say this question Will be deleted?

Comment: Take a minute to read FAQ, it tells you how to ask a question so it can be answered. You will also understand why your question got closed. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Oh and, you can prevent the deletion by askig good questions that are useful, unsubjective and have to do with programming. Programming is not where can I find programmers, etc...

Comment: You can also discuss this site itself and how to ask questions here on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hint:  Focus is important.

Comment: @S.Lott, I don't think subtlety would work here.

Comment: You should read [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: @Alex B: Trying not to be "subtle" but "simple".  Simply write questions with a simple focus and a simple topic.  It seems to simple and unsubtle.

Comment: Without having read any of the closed questions: if applicable then maybe [Where can I ask questions that aren't programming questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions) can help.

Comment: [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ask specific questions, don't post your list of requirements and let us figure out your architecture. If you can't manage to do that, you probably should look for something else to do.

Comment: What is wrong with list of requirements?

Comment: @mathepic: List of requirements is absolutely fine. Only list of requirements is not. I mean the "I have to do xxxx using yyyy and zzzz. Give me the codez" type of questions mean you just want someone to do the work for you. On the other end "I have to do xxxx using yyyy and zzzz. I've tried doing <insert code here> but I get <insert error here> when doing xxxx. I tried to change <some code> to <some other code> but it did not help". This is a better question.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9):

Try reading your questions out loud before submitting them (of course, minus code snippets), then ask yourself the following questions:

- Does this make sense at all? If I read this to someone over the phone, would they understand what I am asking?
- Did I just waste a lot of breath to ask a simple question?
- Did I provide a lot of supporting details, but fail to connect them to my question?

And finally:

- Is it easy to ascertain what my question is in the first place?

Its very common to come here and post a question when you are stuck on something, which naturally means you have a heightened sense of urgency. Just try and remember that we do **not** share your sense of urgency and do **not** have the background to your problem in our head like you do.

A good outline is:

1. This is what I'm trying to accomplish
2. This is what I've done so far
3. This is where I'm stuck
4. This is my OS / Compiler / Language Version / etc information

In your question, you really don't make #1 even remotely clear until the bottom of the assignment that you pasted, and even there its very ambiguous.

Re-writing your question (in meta form) (no pun intended):

1. I'm trying to work through an assignment
2. I'm stuck even starting because I don't understand this terminology:

   Short clip of the assignment where `distributed' is used
3. I don't know how this should impact my design, if at all
4. I'm using (language X / db server X / operating system Y)

Then, tag your question appropriately and ***monitor*** activity on it, be quick to respond to comments and make revisions as needed.

I think you saw such a negative response because after reading through the long winded paste of the assignment details, it still was not clear what was being asked and people might have thought that you just wanted them to do your homework. I didn't interpret it that way, but a lot of people might.

Don't get discouraged, its just another learning experience. A room full of millions of programmers is almost ***never*** going to be a gentle place (depends on what you put in the brownies, and who likes sweets).

Comment: Great post. This should be in the FAQ.

Answer (score 7):

Judging by your last question, you're looking for do-my-homework.com, but it doesn't exist.  Did you try asking your teacher for help?

Comment: ? because of lack of proper guidance!

Answer (score 3):

This question isn't very easy to answer also. What you need to do is to

1. Find something specific that you are not able to do. When you give a huge description of what you want and then say "how can i do this?" it is very hard to give help without actually writing the program for you. Spend some time with your problem, identify what you are not able to do (if it is nothing, then you'd better get back to a tutorial if it out of interest that you are programming or your teacher if you are learning to program in some course).
2. Be concise. People don't want to do your work for you. At any forum online, people would like to help you out, but only if you can tell them what you want help with. If you say, "help me", someone will have to figure out what you want help with. Nobody likes to do that.
3. Type things out properly. It is very irritating for many people to see badly written *long* questions. Your question doesn't seem to have properly written sentences (lots of unnecessary comments *inside* sentences) and use capitals wherever appropriate it will make reading your question a far smaller pain. **DON'T USE CAPITAL LETTERS UNNECESSARILY!**

Comment: thank you, have to select a answer yours is the kind one, but no one has suggested other similar sites like stackoverflow which can be used for asking.........